# how to save highscore for each level

Tags: android

I have 3 levels in the game and I want to store each levels highscore as they are played. User can go back to the level and can challenge their own highscore. Now how will I save the level highscore of the each level ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most optimal ( and easiest) way to persist your score is to use a SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences pref =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor ed =pref.edit();
        ed.putInt("1",100);
        ed.putint("2",300);
        ed.putInt("3",214);
        ed.commit();
```

Store the high scores like the code above. To get the scores from any level anytime ( for example level 2) , use :

```
 SharedPreferences pref =    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int highscore = pref.getInt("2",-1);
```

Comment: choose an answer as the right one so that other user could see which answer to choose from.

Comment: Thanks dude I was looking for this only ....do check this post. I mite need your help if i stuck ..thanks a ton ..

Comment: i will be glad to help :). post new queries as a different question .

Answer (score 0):

[In a database?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.